# While building a gem i get an error: "No implicit conversion of String into Integer"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am new to programming in Ruby. I was following the example of creating a new gem. But when I issue the command to build the gem (gem build packagename.spec), I am getting an error.

Here is my code snippet:

```
     Gem::Specification.new do |s| 

           s.name = "moviesAndPlaylists" 
           s.version = "1.0.0" 
           s.author = "Chetan Yewale" 
           s.email = "yewalechetan@gmail.com" 
           s.summary = "Plays and reviews movies" 
           s.description = File.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'README') 
           s.homepage = "http://github.com/" 
           s.files = Dir["{bin, lib, spec}/**/*"] + %w(LICENSE README) 
           s.test_files = Dir["spec/**/*"] 
           s.executables = [ 'moviesAndPlaylists' ] 

           s.required_ruby_version = '>=1.9' 
           s.add_development_dependecy 'rspec' 

     end
```

Please let me know what is wrong? Why do I get an error message like:

```
Invalid gemspec in [moviesAndPlaylists.gemspec]: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
ERROR:  Error loading gemspec. Aborting.
```

I tried commenting out some lines and starting again, but could not figure it out. If anybody has encountered this error before, please let me know,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the line

```
s.executables = [ 'moviesAndPlaylists' ]
```

to

```
s.executables << 'moviesAndPlaylists'
```

Look the [documentation of executables](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#executables).

Comment: Hey Arup, Thanks for the answer. That issue is resolved. But, I still get an error while building the gem at the last line.

Comment: The error is                                                   Invalid gemspec in [moviesAndPlaylists.gemspec]: undefined method `add_development_dependecy' for #<Gem::Specification:0x152d554 moviesAndPlaylists-1.0.0>
ERROR:  Error loading gemspec. Aborting.                                                            I am using gem version 2.1.11. Does this version have a different way of specifying dependencies?

Comment: @user3677377  Why not checking the documentation I linked ?

Comment: Sorry, It was really silly of me. There was a spelling mistake in the second last line. Thanks for the link of documentation though. I am new to Ruby and StackOverflow :-)  From now onwards, I will consult the documentation first.